# Spring boot 1.4.x and custom CharsetProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gsm

I'm trying to register a custom CharsetProvider to be able to use X-Gsm7Bit encoding. I use https://github.com/OpenSmpp/opensmpp/tree/master/charset/src/main/java/org/smpp/charset provider from Logica.
To register this new charset provider I use `META-INF/services/java.nio.charsets.spi.CharsetProvider` file with the content `org.smpp.charset.Gsm7BitCharsetProvider`.

I can't make it working. 
The sources of a test application are here https://github.com/asmsoft/provider

I get `java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider: Provider org.smpp.charset.Gsm7BitCharsetProvider not found` when I start it as a fat jar

```
mvn clean
mvn package
java -jar target/provider-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

If I start it with `mvn spring-boot:run` I get `java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: X-Gsm7Bit`

And everything works well when I start the application with my IDE.

Currently I solved my problem as follows: I've put jar providing custom charset into `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` and everything works as expected again, the charset is being registered on the boot.

I'm not happy with this solution and I'd like to ask for your help.

Comment: The move from `lib` to `BOOT-INF/lib` for the nested jar shouldn't make any difference as both are only visible to Boot's class loader rather than the JVM's app class loader. Can you provide a small sample that reproduces the problem and illustrates how and when you're trying to use the custom provider?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson , Thanks for reply, I've changed the description of the problem and added a link to a test application.

Answer (score 4):

As [Andy Wilkinson mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39658178/190685), you probably hit a bug, namely this one (created in 2002): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4619777

I don't know if this solves your problem, but you can get the `Charset` by using the `CharsetProvider` directly, something in the line of:

```
Charset charset = new CharsetProvider().charsetForName("...");
```

You might even create a utility method to get a `Charset` with manual fallbacks to `CharsetProvider`s:

```
Charset getCharset(String charsetName) {
    if (Charset.isSupported(charsetName)) {
        return Charset.forName(charsetName);
    }

    Charset charset = new org.smpp.charset.Gsm7BitCharsetProvider().charsetForName(charsetName);
    if (charset != null) { return charset; }
    charset = new com.beetstra.jutf7.CharsetProvider().charsetForName(charsetName);
    if (charset != null) { return charset; }
    // more fallbacks here ...
    return null;
}
```

Although this would only be a workaround for the mentioned JDK bug, since this is exactly the logic that would automatically be performed by registering `CharsetProvider`s.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've encountered a bug in the JDK. The [javadoc for `CharsetProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html) says:

> Charset providers are looked up via the current thread's context class loader

However, the [code that looks up the providers](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/7bdd8c20b8b3/src/share/classes/java/nio/charset/Charset.java#l340) tells a different story:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ServiceLoader<CharsetProvider> sl =
    ServiceLoader.load(CharsetProvider.class, cl);
```

As you can see, it's using the system class loader and not the thread's context class loader.

It works in your IDE because your application's classes and their dependencies are all available to the system class loader. When you package your application in a fat jar, it fails as your application's classes and their dependencies are then available to Spring Boot's class loader which is a child of the system class loader. You'd have the same problem in any environment where another class loader is used, for example a traditional war deployment to a servlet container.

To avoid the problem, you need to make the provider available to the system class loader. As you've discovered, putting its jar in `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` is one way to achieve that. Other options include using a shaded jar rather than a fat jar, or post-processing the fat jar to add the provider's classes directly to the root of the jar rather than as a nested jar.

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes, I know about that classloaders issue, I just wondered if there any way to resolve it suitable using particularly spring boot starter and fat jar with no copying the provider jar, because it demands more deployment and support efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Check /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in your jar file.
Class-Path: custom CharsetProvider jar Location，
You can update /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF direct,or update Pom file when use Mavean package.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your answer. Could you explain in more details the changes you suggest the OP makes to the `pom.xml` and/or `MANIFEST.mf` files ?