# Springboot not loading my charset SPI library

Tags: spring-boot, charset

I have a charset library, MyCharsetProvider.jar, containing SP code as a subclass of java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider as per specs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html)..
and in src\main\resources\META-INF\services\java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider containing com.myorg.MyCharsetProvider.  This SPI will respond for MyCharset with another charset name..

In my sprintboot app, pom.xml my charset provider is referred. I am calling charset.forName("MyCharset"), within eclipse when I ran (i.e not jar), JVM is able to call MyCharsetProvider.. however when i build a jar via maven and run the jar, JVM does not recognize the presence of MyCharsetProvider.

any ideas what is happening?

Comment: did you find an answer to your problem. I am facing the same issue. How strange that two Sathish Kumars face the same problem for which I am not able to find solution online :P

Comment: Hi @Sathish - Too much of coincidence on this niche issue :)
I believe the issue was solved by using maven shade plugin that took care of it automatically.  ref# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641604/spring-boot-1-4-x-and-custom-charsetprovider

Comment: Thanks @Sathish Kumar. For me the problem was that a library was registering its own service which was overriding mine. Thanks for your reply though.