# Spring boot 2.7.3 and custom CharsetProvider

Tags: maven-shade-plugin, java-17, uberjar, charset

I'm trying to register a custom CharsetProvider.
As suggested in the [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641604/spring-boot-1-4-x-and-custom-charsetprovider](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) post we upgraded our application to use maven shade plugin for packaging which was automatically registering our custom charset provider and things were working fine till our application app was in Spring boot 2.7.3 and java 11. Once we tried upgrading our application to Java 17, again our custom charset provider was not loaded.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Upgraded java version to 17 and expected shade plugin to work the same way it was working with java 11.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mre].